# How to deal with @string properties in custom component of android?

Tags: android, custom-component

In layout xml file, I set properties using @string like this:

```
<com.hardpass.MyCustomComponent
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    mynamespace:title="@string/xxootitle" />
```

How to deal with `@string/xxootitle` in custom component `com.hardpass.MyCustomComponent`?
Or how to parse `@string/xxootitle` to the real value which is defined in strings.xml.

```
String title = attrs.getAttributeValue(mynamespace, "title"); 
//the title got here is "@string/xxootitle",
//but how to parse `@string/xxootitle` to the real value which is defined in strings.xml.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use getAttributeResourceValue and getString,

```
getString(attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(mynamespace, "title", R.string.xxootitle));
```